# Windows 10 PC not being issued IP after OS reinstall

Tags: networking, router, ip, network-adapter, mac-address

**The issue:** My router will not issue me a DHCP IP to connect via the ethernet adapter

**Devices involved, in order of connection:**

- My PC (ethernet adapter on Asrock AB350 Pro4 motherboard)
- A powerline network extender (Netgear PLW1000)
- Frontier router (Arris NVG468MQ)

**Previous configuration:** I had assigned a static IP to my PC before I reinstalled Windows.

**Attempts to solve the problem:**

- Making sure IPv6 was disabled in the NIC's settings
- Making sure that Windows was configured to receive a DHCP address
- TCP/IP stack reset in Windows
- Manually assigning an IP in the router
- Spoofing my NIC's MAC address
- NIC driver reinstallation
- Complete reinstall of Windows
- Complete factory reset of both powerline and router

The ethernet adapter has no connection-specific DNS suffic, no default gateway, and has been assigned an APIPA address. I don't know what to do at this point. I have seemingly exhausted the solutions that often work for people, and anything I find on the internet I've already tried. Please help me figure out why this is happening.

Thanks!

Comment: Does DHCP work for other machines on the same LAN?

Comment: Yes. I saw a suggestion to install the NIC driver from the motherboard manufacturer, and that ended up working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing the NIC driver from the Asrock's website, this fixed my issue.